# select first two characters of values in a concatenated string

Tags: salesforce, formula

I am trying to create a formula field that checks a string that is a series of concatenated values separated by a comma.  I want to check the first two characters of each comma separated value in the string.  For example, the string pattern could be: abcd,efgh,ijkl,mnop,qrst,uvwx

In my formula I'd like to check if the first two characters are 'ab','ef'

If so, I would return true, else false.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this properly, you need to use a regular expression.  Unfortunately the REGEX function is not available in formula fields.  It is, however, available in formulas in Validation Rules and in Workflow Rules.  You can, therefore, specify the below formula in either of a Validation or Workflow Rule:

```
OR(
AND(
    NOT(
        BEGINS( KXENDev__Languages__c, "ab" )
    ),
    NOT(
        BEGINS( KXENDev__Languages__c, "ef" )
    )
),
REGEX( KXENDev__Languages__c , ".*,(?!ab|ef).*")
)
```

If it's a Validation Rule, you're done -- this formula will create an error if any of the entries do *not* start with "ab" or "ef".  If it's a Workflow Rule, then you can add a Field Update to it to update some field with False when this formula is true (if this formula is true then there is at least one item that doesn't start with ab or ef, so that would make your field False).

Some may ask "What's with the BEGINS statements?  Couldn't you have done this all with one REGEX?"  Yes, I probably could, but that makes for an increasingly complex REGEX statement, and these are quite difficult to debug in Salesforce.com, so I prefer to keep my REGEXes in Salesforce.com as simple as possible.

Comment: BTW you could also do this quite simply in Apex without using any kind of regular expression, but by using the String.split() method instead, splitting on commas, and then comparing the first two characters to ab and ef.

Comment: It's actually a formula field where I need this.  I want the formula to return true if any of the entries start with the specified two characters and false otherwise.  Will the above work in a formula?

Comment: No, the above won't work in a formula field, but you can do it in a workflow rule with a field update to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to search for ',ab' and ',ef' using CONTAINS method. But first of all you need to re implement method which composes this string so it puts ',' before first substring. At the end returned string should look like ',abcd,efgh,ijkl,mnop,qrst,uvwx'.
If you are not able to re implement method which compose this string use LEFT([our string goes here],2) method to check first two chars.

Comment: This won't work because you want to find any entries that are *not* starting with ab and ef.

Comment: No, if you read his post closely, it appears that he's looking to catch any elements that *don't* start with ab or ef.  So if you have a string like abcd,efgh,xyza your method won't work because the string does contain ab (or ,ab in your modified version) and ,ef but there's still an invalid entry in there in ,xyza.